# Should this general PBTA tag be removed when there is already Dungeon World tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Does this trigger violate GM principles? Can it be fixed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/does-this-trigger-violate-gm-principles-can-it-be-fixed)

This question has [powered-by-the-apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powered-by-the-apocalypse) and [dungeon-world](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-world)

Should the PBTA tag removed since Dungeon World defines what the question is about better?

The question also specifically deals with Dungeon World and not the mechanic of general PBTA games

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### When you don't know where the best answer is, it's okay to go a little wider.

It's a question about homebrew. I can see value in casting a wider net out to related systems in case something out there has taken a similar tack.

(even though in this case IMO that similar tack was right in their own backyard)